# Can negative edge weights in a graph be positive numbers?

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal, weighted-graphs, theory

I'm a little confused by the concept of a "negative" edge weight.  All of the examples I have seen represent negative edge weights as negative numbers.  Is it possible for an edge weight to carry a negative weight, and be represented as a positive number?

As an example, suppose we had a graph of a network where the edges represent the time elapsed for data to travel between server A and server B.  Suppose that we had a weight on each edge representing the lag time between certain servers (so perhaps the time for the data to travel between A and B has a lag of time t, which means the total time can be shown as the time to get to B from A, plus the lag).  Is "lag" a negative edge weight in this case, even though it is a positive number?

Comment: You are free to interpret your weights exactly how you feel like.

Comment: Why would you see that lag as a negative weight ? And what is the meaning of "the time to get to B from A" vs. "the lag" ? Aren't they the same thing ?

Comment: @PålGD: are you free to say that -1 is a positive number ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I consider -1 a very positive number.   Much more positive than for example -2.  I also think of 1 as a much more negative number than other numbers such as 2.

Comment: @PålGD: one says 'larger' and 'smaller', not 'more positive'/'more negative'. And "more positive" does not coincide with "positive". -1 being "very positive" is absurd. In fact, -1 is red and -2 is redder.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/160629/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/76452139/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

A positive weight is a positive number. A negative weight is a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

The negative and positive refers to the sign of the number, i.e., a negative weight = negative number.

The reason why negative weights are important is because many algorithms only work when the edge weights are a non-negative.

A simple example of an algorithm is Dijkstra's Algorithm to find shortest paths in a graph. It doesn't work on graphs with negative weight. An example of such a graph is the following (if Dijkstra is run starting at node $a$):

[image]

In the example you gave above, intuitively it seems that lag time should be a positive number (since you'd want to minimise it), but it depends on the application, and I suppose both representations should work.